# C++ Construction of Static Lambda Member of Template type

Tags: c++, lambda, static

I have a class that contains a static member, the member is a lambda. 
The lambda does have fixed arguments but might have different captures. This is where the problem comes in. This static member is not default constructible.

It sort of must be static too and I cannot use type erasure patterns as it is on an embedded system. Anybody have any ideas or patterns that solve this problem.

I can do in-place construction on a byte array of measured size but that creates its own problems and I want to avoid it.

What I have but don't like is:

**EDIT 1 : Improved Example**
More complete example found here:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/UMwsXSR6c2QYleiU

**EDIT 2 : Further Improved Example**
Improved version of the above:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/VTvGNlFRCNYG4J00

**EDIT 3 : Fixed bug with return_t**
https://wandbox.org/permlink/tl4BaH1zbutMV2nU

Comment: You know your class `Lambda` is not a *lambda*, but an badly named custom callable class? See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for lambdas. Some issues for you to consider: Copy-/Move- constructing/assigning, destructing, alignment.

Comment: Yeah I know I should rename it. One moment.
Ok fixed, yeah I understand the issues, this is a pretty specific embedded use case, and I'll add the destructor call at some point but I wanted to keep this example simple.
What alignment issues do you foresee with this implementation?

I will never be supporting copy construction with this, nor assignment of any kind, the defaults here will be explicitly deleted.

Comment: Seems kind of dangerous.  If someone creates two instances of `StaticLambdaWrapper` using the same type, then the second instance will overwrite the data for the first.  But what's your goal here?  Why wrap the lambda instead of just storing it directly?

Comment: Because it must be referenced by a static member function and overriding in this case is desirable.
I already know that when an override takes place I must detect and destruct the previous item.

Comment: More stuff in my example:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/4Otgy3LdT3Vi7nWu

[C++11: 5.1.2/3]: The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed non-union class type — called the closure type — whose properties are described below. This class type is not an aggregate (8.5.1). The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the corresponding lambda-expression.

Comment: I don't see anything particularly wrong with your solution (if your platform has no special alignment requirements for lambdas). I'd still try std::function. Chances are, SOO will kick in and eliminate dynamic allocation in your case.

Comment: I don't see the point of make the member `static`, as it is mostly unusable without the instance anyway to retrieve the true type (because of the lambda).

Comment: [OT] `void f(); void bar() {return f();}` is valid, no need to dispatch on return type of `f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to do something like this

```
template <class T>
class StaticWrapper
{
    static T* t = nullptr;
    StaticWrapper(T&& tt) { 
        static T ttt {tt};
        t = &ttt;
    }
};
```

Same idea but no finicky casts and placement new.

Comment: Yeah, might as well let the compiler handle the boolean for the static's construction :).
Actually quite a useful pattern this.

Comment: Actually, i think I can use it to work around this issue entirely :D